# Is possible to record for mobile app testcases using appium server in ubuntu?

Tags: appium, appium-android

I need to record a testcases for a react-native mobile application in ubntu using appium.

And I don't have a appium UI in ubntu. anyone can suggest how to open appium UI on my ubuntu system.

Comment: get it from here:
https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases/tag/v1.2.6

Comment: Thanks for your response @lalongooo. already am configured it. now i have some issues on access the react-native properties (Views).